# What are the cons of using in-place collection initializers in Java

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, initialization, set

Consider this piece of code:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(){{add("foo");add("boo");}};
```

or for the `HashMap`:

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>(){{put("foo","bar");put("boo","jar");}};
```

Pros are simply to find: less lines of code, conciseness. But what are the cons?

**UPD**: The question is not only about sets, but about all types of collections, added `Map` to illustrate this.

Comment: The con: it does not compile :-p You forgot to name the set and to add a ;

Comment: Consciousness? living, thinking code? I think you mean conciseness ;)

Comment: Good news: Java 8 is slated to support collection literals. Bad news: it took us five years to get Java 7.

Comment: @Andy: What do those literals look like?

Comment: @Lukas Eder - Here's the original proposal from Joshua Bloch. There are literals for lists, sets and maps. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001193.html

Comment: `Set<Senator> honestSenators = {};`... he's a funny guy :-) Thanks Andy!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you do that, you are creating an anonymous subclass of HashSet, which means you are unnecessarily polluting your code base with classes that don't do anything new.

How about this instead?

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
```

Or alternatively, use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s [`Sets`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) class. It has factory methods to initialize different kinds of sets:

```
Set<String> set = Sets.newHashSet("foo", "bar");
```

With Maps it's trickier, but you can use [`ImmutableMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html):

```
Map<String,String> myMap = 
    ImmutableMap.of("foo","bar","boo","jar");
```

or (mutable version)

```
Map<String,String> myMutableMap =
        Maps.newHashMap(ImmutableMap.of("foo","bar","boo","jar"));
```

Without external libraries, you can still initialize a Map with a single entry:

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>(
    Collections.singleTonMap("foo","bar")
);
```

but that be one ugly beast, if you ask me.

---

> UPD: The question is not only about sets, but about all types of
>   collections, added Map to illustrate this.

Guava has several Factory classes like this:

[`Sets`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html), [`Maps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html), [`Lists`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html), [`Multimaps`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html), [`Multisets`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multisets.html), [`Ranges`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ranges.html)

Comment: I prefer your code for readability, but is creating an anonymous class truly a downside? The fact that it is anonymous mean that it doesn't show up as another file in your source tree. The costs of loading just one extra class in the classloader is so negligible as to be meaningless in most scenarios (when most apps load tens of thousands of classes).

Comment: @matt: As soon as you start doing that, you'll do it all over your code-base and you'll have 100's of useless classes, for which you have to increase your PermGen space... So better not do it

Comment: @matt b I agree that the cost is negligible, but I'm happy about any anonymous class I can avoid. Especially subclassing a non-abstract class in java.util seems like a code smell to me, but that's just me, I guess.

Comment: On the topic of "unnecessarily polluting your code base with classes" I take it that; anonymous class = bad, extra libraries which do the same thing = good ;) ?

Comment: @Sean I modified question to address not only Set, but Map too.

Comment: @Lukas, each class could waste KBs of memory. ;) If you are writing 100s of these you should be loading data from an external source, IMHO.

Comment: @Peter very witty and very valid remark! I try to restrict the extra libraries I use as well as the extra classes I create. But I have found that using Guava reduces the number of classes I have to create significantly. And the Guava guys never fail to point out that you should use Guava with ProGuard, stripping it down to what you really need.

Answer (score 3):

Con: This will result in an anonymous class, which has to be loaded by the class loader. If you do that 500'000 times, I'm sure you'll run into `OutOfMemoryExceptions`

Answer (score 2):

It is much more difficult to read this way, especially with the {{ and }}.

Answer (score 1):

Persoanlly I find it easier to read, but it is entirely down to taste.

The main con is when the `equals()` for a class does a

```
if (getClass() != ThisClass.class) return false;
```

The anonynous class is a sub-class and can break the `equals()` method depending on how it has been implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as far as I know it's a bad practice to compare collections that way. I mean invoking equals on the entire collection is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

They don't work with gson anymore.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> m;

m = new HashMap<String, Object>(){{ put("a", "b"); }};
System.out.println(gson.toJson(m)); // null


m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
m.put("a", "b");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(m)); // {"a":"b"}
```